# A fully understood living organism

Tags: biochemistry, molecular-biology, cell-biology

I have no background in biology but in the context of other research I am wondering if there is an organism, however simple it is, whose functions and structure is fully understood by biology or biochemistry. This would mean that all the functions and roles of all its genes are documented and all its internal procceses also. In other words is there an organism that can be fully analyzed in terms of its chemical processes and its RNA/DNA?

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE! It depends on what you mean by _fully_. We don't know function of every gene present in **any** organism (we don't even know how many genes we have!). However, if you exclude some processes from your list, most probably _E. coli_ or _C. elegans_ might fit in.

Comment: No, there is not. Biological organisms are complex and have substances/interactions which have yet to be discovered. We are discovering new things about relatively simple organisms every day. However, the closest you will come is a "simple" bacteria like a ssp. of E.coli. Better yet, a virus, if one could classify it as an organism.

Comment: I was asking this question because I was trying to come up with examples of "strong emergence". The idea that there can be properties of very complex systems that are irreducible to the properties or even the interactions of its constituent parts. The property of conciusness is an example of strong emergence and I guess the emotional effects of music is another one. From your answers I can see that there are examples of strong emergence even in single cell organisms.